# Isabelle combinatoric proof Cayley's formula

Tags: isabelle, hol

I am getting started with Isabelle HOL and want to try to construct a combinatorial proof of some kind. I took Cayley's formula for the start.

Here it is:
**For every positive integer n, the number of trees on n labeled vertices is  n^{n-2}.**

How would one work wit something like that in Isabelle? I am assuming I will have to define trees, but then what?

Any help or related articles and or codes would be very much appreciated! Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you provide a link/reference for the proof that you are interested in formalizing (there is quite a number of different proofs available in the literature)? Also, what have you tried so far? As a side note, if you are only getting started with Isabelle/HOL and do not have experience with other proof assistants, my advice would be to start with simpler problems, perhaps with problems from standard textbooks on Isabelle (e.g., http://concrete-semantics.org/, https://functional-algorithms-verified.org/).

Answer (score 1):

The idea of the proof would be:

1. define trees (or use any existing one)
2. follow a paper proof by that proves that

```
card {tree. nodes tree = n \<and> canonical tree} = n ^ (n-2)
```

where `nodes` gives the number of nodes and `canonical` is some kind of invariant that the tree is normalized (e.g., you have correct labels going from 0 to n-1).

I have tried proving or defining anything, but I suspect that this is a hard theorem to start with in Isabelle, because I expect that you will need either more general theorems on graphs or you will need to work a lot on bijection due the fact that the node are labeled.